# Does Go have serialization like php?

Tags: php, go

Does Go have serialization with plain text result like PHP function serialize()?

String
s:size:value;

Integer
i:value;

Boolean
b:value; (does not store "true" or "false", does store '1' or '0')

Null
N;

Array
a:size:{key definition;value definition;(repeated per element)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest of [php.serialize](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.serialize.php) would be the [encoding package](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/) with methods like `MarshalText()` / `UnmarshalText()`: any object implementing the interface [`TextMarshaler`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/#TextMarshaler)/[`TextUnmarshaler`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/#TextUnmarshaler) would be serializable.
(And you have the same feature for binary marshal/unmarshal)

You can see [examples for JSON](https://gobyexample.com/json), but you can find other projects for other type of data:

- [`ajg/form`](https://github.com/ajg/form): a Form Encoding & Decoding Package for Go
- [chai2010/protorpc](https://github.com/chai2010/protorpc): Google Protocol Protobufs RPC for Go

Answer (score 1):

Well, not exactly.

There's [gob](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/) which is binary, or you can use [json](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) (same as php's [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) / [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

For cross-language (binary) solutions there're few options:

- [Cap'n Proto](http://kentonv.github.io/capnproto/)
- [msgpack](https://github.com/vmihailenco/msgpack)
- [protobufs rpc](https://github.com/chai2010/protorpc)